# Dynamically move control somewhere else in the call stack

Tags: r

In [this use case](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/1131), I want to dynamically move control somewhere else in the call stack. Is this possible? Below, can we make `top_level()` return 2 if we modify `return_2_from_top_level()` and leave the body of `top_level()` alone?

```r
# Do not modify this:
top_level <- function() {
  return_2_from_top_level()
  Sys.sleep(2)
  1
}

# Modify this:
return_2_from_top_level <- function() {
  # What can we do here to make top_level() return 2?
  evalq(return(2), sys.frame(1)) # Does not work, but kind of shows the idea.
}

# We want 2, not 1:
top_level()
#> [1] 1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Desired result:

```r
top_level()
#> [1] 2

# We still want this function body for top_level():
body(top_level)
#> {
#>     return_2_from_top_level()
#>     Sys.sleep(2)
#>     1
#> }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As G. Grothendieck pointed out in his answer, I did have to modify my setup. However, I found that custom error conditions served this purpose quite nicely, and the result was minimally invasive: https://github.com/ropensci/drake/pull/1135. Minimal example:

```r
# This is what we actually call:
higher_level <- function() {
  tryCatch(
    top_level(),
    custom = function(e) {
      2
    }
  )
}

# Unmodified as promised:
top_level <- function() {
  return_2_from_top_level()
  Sys.sleep(2)
  1
}

# Modified:
return_2_from_top_level <- function() {
  stop(custom_condition())
}

custom_condition <- function() {
  structure(
    list(call = NULL, message = ""),
    class = c("custom", "error", "condition")
  )
}

higher_level()
#> [1] 2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you can modify your whole setup to avoid this in the first place but if not then `callCC` could be used.

**1)** What is important is that `return_2_from_top_level` must know about `g` so we reset the indicated function environments to that within `top` where `g` is known.

```
return_2_from_top_level <- function() g(2)

top_level <- function() { 
  return_2_from_top_level()
  Sys.sleep(2)
  1
}

top <- function(g) {
  environment(return_2_from_top_level) <- environment()
  environment(top_level) <- environment()
  top_level()   
}

callCC(top)
## [1] 2
```

**2)** Alternately we can move the definitions of `top_level` and 
`return_2__from_top_level` into `top` in which case there is no explicit messing with environments.

```
top <- function(g) {

  return_2_from_top_level <- function() g(2)

  top_level <- function() { 
    return_2_from_top_level()
    Sys.sleep(2)
    1
  }

  top_level()   

}

callCC(top)
## [1] 2
```

**3)** Another possibility is to copy `g` into the global environment.

```
return_2_from_top_level <- function() g(2)

top_level <- function() { 
  return_2_from_top_level()
  Sys.sleep(2)
  1
}

top <- function(g) {
  g <<- g
  top_level()   
}

callCC(top)
## [1] 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I actually found that custom error conditions did the trick: https://github.com/ropensci/drake/pull/1135. It did involve changing my own setup, like you predicted, but it turned out to be minimally invasive. I will post an alternative solution soon.